# Getting DIV with specific ID to the top of TinyMCE editor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE as HTML editor with Asp.net and MVC3.
 I have Html something like this

```
<html>
<div id  = "A1" ........../>
<div id  = "A1" ........../>
<div id  = "A1" ........../>
</html>
```

Also, I have 3 different buttons, clicking on which, the appropriate  in html should scroll and come to the top of Editor.

e.g If I click on button "A1", the DIV with id "A1" should come to the top and likewise.

I saw some timy mce API called "getBookmark", but I dont know how to use it.
Or is there any other approach which will help me achieve the above purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scroll to a specified element you may use

```
$(tinymce.activeEditor.getBody()).find('#A1').get(0).scrollIntoView();
```